# jquery select list auto populate on load

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to convert my OLDSCHOOL javascript select list function to jquery..

I've got it working (for the most part), but its not pretty... one thing that doesnt work is when the page is loaded, i would like the 3 select lists to be pre-loaded already with their unique data, although only the first one (CLIENT) is loaded and then is waiting for 'change' trigger to populate the one below and so on...

I've researched and there are many examples to do this, but ive been trying for awhile and can't get any of them to work.. the only way i got it to work is doing it this way... maybe someone can help me out?

JS:

```
    ////// TASK SELECT LIST
$('#projectSelect').on('change', function() {
    $.getJSON('cpp.php?task='+this.value, function(data) {
        var select = $('#taskSelect');
        select.empty();

        $.each(data, function(key, val){
        select.append("<option value='"+this.id+"'>"+this.label+"</option>");
        });
    });
})

    ////// PROJECT SELECT LIST
$('#clientSelect').on('change', function() {
    $.getJSON('cpp.php?client='+this.value, function(data) {
        var select = $('#projectSelect');
        select.empty();

        $.each(data, function(key, val){
        select.append("<option value='"+this.id+"'>"+this.label+"</option>");
        });
    });
})

    ////// CLIENT SELECT LIST
    $.getJSON('cpp.php', function(data) {
        var select = $('#clientSelect');
        $.each(data, function(key, val){
        select.append("<option value='"+this.id+"'>"+this.label+"</option>");
        });

    });
```

image:
[image]

Comment: "I'm trying to convert my OLDSCHOOL javascript select list function to jquery." Why?

Comment: old way caused me too many issues which i had to use little hacks to sort lists alphabetically..etc... hashtables.. blah

Comment: Don't wrap the $.getJSON calls inside change events and it should populate when the code is executed.

Comment: yeah but i still want the lists to change when another value is selected